# CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target

Tags: error-handling

I'm trying to install light sensors on gazebo and I was following the steps from [Creating and adding a Custom ROS light sensor plugin](https://github.com/SMARTlab-Purdue/ros-tutorial-gazebo-simulation/wiki/Sec.-4:-Creating-a-light-sensor-plugin).
I've done all the steps but when I tried to do `catkin_make` on the step as shown here:

[image: shown here]

I'm getting these errors:

[image: errors]

can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like cmake is complaining it can't find your source file.

Looking at [this bit of the directions](https://github.com/SMARTlab-Purdue/ros-tutorial-gazebo-simulation/blob/master/README_full.md#4-installation-of-relevant-dependenciespackages), are you sure you put your .cc file into the `src` directory and named it exactly `light_sensor_plugin.cpp`?

If you could, can you run `tree` on the source directory so we can see where all your files are?

Comment: Hi, yes I did but not it's giving me a different error. I don't know what is going on....